# Computing monthly payment

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to compute the monthly payment in my code based on this formula but my code is not showing the results I expected.  What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
MthlyPmt = CDbl(LoanAmt * IntRate / (1 - (1 + IntRate) ^ -DurationMths))
```

Variables and values used:

```
  LoanAmt = CDbl(txtLoanAmt.Text)

  IntRate = CDbl(txtIntRate.Text) / 100

  DurationMths = CDbl(txtDurationMths.Text)
```

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting the wrong result? Is there an error? It will also help to include any relevant tags on your question so the right people see it. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: What results are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: Post your expected result, and what it's outputting. It's probably a precedence issue or something.

Comment: the amount is computing incorrectly.  Rather the monthly payment amount.  Wondering if my mthlypmt formulat is incorrect?

Comment: Give specific input (numbers), actual output and expected output. [Edit] your question, don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear because you don't provide much information.
if this is not what you are looking for then please update your question with more detail and info.

if you want to calculate monthly payment you need to do:

Lets say loan amount is 1000
Lets say rate is 10% 
"loanAmt / 100 * IntRate" wil give you the amount. "100"

To get the total amount he needs to pay you need to do
loanAmt + (loanAmt / 100 * IntRate) wil give you the amount "1100"
you also need to put is in () like "(loanAmt + (loanAmt / 100 * IntRate))"

Then you can devide that amount with the mounths he is going to pay it back
(loanAmt + (loanAmt / 100 * IntRate)) / DurationMths

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MthlyPmt As Double
    Dim loanAmt As Double
    Dim IntRate As Double
    Dim DurationMths As Double

    loanAmt = CDbl(txtLoanAmt.Text)
    IntRate = CDbl(txtIntRate.Text)
    DurationMths = CDbl(txtDurationMths.Text)
    MthlyPmt = (loanAmt + (loanAmt / 100 * IntRate)) / DurationMths

    Result.Text = MthlyPmt
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not how monthly paiement are calculated. With your formula, for 5 year it would be around 18$/month but in reality (let say a car loan) it would be a bit more than 21/month.

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula is wrong. If you take a look [here](http://www.hughcalc.org/formula.php). You will see that J is monthly interest rate.

```
IntRate = CDbl(txtIntRate.Text) / (12 * 100)
```